# Use of ございます to describe existence

Tags: keigo

Why in this dialog is「ございません」the appropriate answer?

「兄弟がありますか。」「いいえ。私は兄弟が（＿＿＿）。

I understand that ございません would parallel あります in the first sentence, but shouldn't I use the polite form of iru to describe the non-existence of living things?

Comment: How old is the book/materials you are using?

Comment: Is this a translation from a non-Japanese source? Because 「ありますか」is used in objects and plants only. the correct form should be 「兄弟はいますか。」or「兄弟はいらっしゃいますか。」

Comment: @BurakUeda that's a bit of an oversimplification, it is possible to use ある with people

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The material is from a website and pretty new. I guess I'm just wondering why it's OK to use ございます instead of おります to show the existence of people; does it have to do with context?

Comment: That usage is dated and obsolete today.